# How to populate a cell by giving start letter

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

Lets assume, in excel, I have a cell which I want a data as Auto, Close, Trigger.

I want to populate it automatically if I type just the first char i.e For Auto, just A and hit Enter, it should fill as Auto..

Comment: Lets assume you've made an effort to solve this yourself before posting here. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42507447/edit) your question to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your worksheet name and select *View Code*. Paste this in and change `A1` to whatever your specific cell is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target = Me.Range("A1") Then
        Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
            Case "A"
                Target.Value = "Auto"
            Case "C"
                Target.Value = "Close"
            Case "T"
                Target.Value = "Trigger"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```